# How to disable tracking/beacon on kia soul ev?

Tags: kia, electric-vehicle, soul, gps

We are about to trade in our 99 Corolla for a Kia Soul EV.  One of the things I really dislike about it is that something (the GPS beacon?) will send location data and possibly other info about our driving habits.  Any idea how to disable this for this particular model?

Comment: Are you talking about [UVO](http://www.kia.com/us/en/content/technology/uvo/introducing-uvo)?

Comment: Short of removing the antenna (means losing gps/radio/sirius) module I don't think you'll be able to do what you want. If you're feeling adventurous pull the antenna module and take a look at the board.

Comment: Yes, I guess I do mean UVO, and I'm not above removing an antenna.

Comment: I don't want a smartphone app.  I don't want help finding my car in a parking lot.  I hate taking directions from a gps.  I don't make phone calls while driving.  I won't pay for satellite radio.  I find the whole computer distracting, but I would probably use it to play normal radio (if it can) and for whatever charging management functions it has.  Mostly I mind that it's sending my data out, either broadcasting to sensors "hey here I am" or giving Kia a map of where I go regularly.  I don't want it collecting my voice recognition data.  Sorry, tech privacy curmudgeon.

Comment: http://news.microsoft.com/2012/05/16/kias-uvo-eservices-keeps-car-owners-informed-and-connected/#sm.00008deu9jdutdh0tps1jubuukbjs

Comment: Is there no "off" button for it? Legitimately curious because many things on modern car infotainment systems have settings to control functionality. On the other hand, I've got a great example of where a setting exists, but it's useless.

Comment: I think the only true answer to this is to refuse to buy any car that has such a device fitted - and make it known to the dealership why you are doing so. If enough people did so they'd stop fitting them (or stop telling you...)

Comment: In my answer [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/89849/ev-tracking-privacy/93732#93732) I talk about removing the cell modem from a Tesla. I'm not sure if a Kia would react the same but every car needs to be able to function without connectivity because some areas have no cell service.

Answer (score 1):

Just looked up the update process for UVO and based on the size of the update, it does look like its running right from that SD card:
https://www.myuvo.com/support/avn40plus_sop/software-update/software-update.shtml

> Make sure you have the following:
>
> ```
> SD Card from your Navigation head unit
> Computer with SD card slot
> Windows XP® or higher or OS X 10.7® or higher
> More than 27GB of free hard disk space
> ```

27GB is big enough to be an OS, nevermind just the "features". Doesn't specify how big the card itself is, but compared to the price of the car, even a 128GB card from a brand name is cheap...

Also:

> If you do not wish to download the update, you may purchase an updated
> SD card from MnSoft America

Never heard of them, but answers where the software comes from.

That being said, I'm betting there's a SIM card in there somewhere that you could remove to kill its connectivity and keep most of the features without letting it report back...

[EDIT: I mentioned keeping it because the UVO page does mention it's being used for diagnostics]

Answer (score 0):

The dealership says driving without the SD card should be sufficient.

Revised: I used to notice that my car lights would occasionally turn themselves on or brighten, seemingly at random.  Having observed this for a long time, I now realize that it happens when joining a highway from an entrance ramp.  Therefore I am quite sure that this answer is incorrect.  The antenna is easy to remove; it just screws off.

Comment: you mean the SIM card? SD cards are for storage, hard to see how that would influence communications.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of suspicious.  It does seem to invalidate every remote operation, though.  No maps, etc.  Maybe it holds the entire operating system for uvo?  What do you think?

Comment: Possible, but then you'd expect to lose the entire user interface on that screen. Can you read the SD card?

Comment: Haven't tried, but it's a good thought.  I bet UVO is provided to Kia on those SDs as a product by MS or whoever, not built in. The "computer" isn't much besides a radio, climate control, setup menu without it.